# Reading input from a file, Scanner.nextLine() produces blank result

Tags: java, regex, file-io

So, my end goal is to use an input file to instantiate an `ArrayList` of Letter objects. The file contains multiple cases of the following format:

```
from-to
line 1
...
line n
```

(*** is used as an indicator of a new letter. There are no blank lines between input lines, in other words, each line is followed immediately by a return and then the next line.)

Yet before I even attempt to instantiate multiple Letter objects, I am just trying to get the first one to work.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(_file).useDelimiter("\\s+?|-");
ArrayList<Letter> letters = new ArrayList();
String from = in.next();
String to = in.next();
Letter temp = new Letter(from,to);
String s = in.next();
temp.addLine(s);
```

Where a Letter object takes two strings for the recipient and writer and can then have lines added to it. So my output should be:

```
Dear Recipient:
Line 1
...
Line n
Sincerely,
Writer
```

But when I use this my output is:

```
Dear Recipient:


Sincerely,
Writer
```

Comment: take a look at this link and update your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry about that. I think the edit should be better, though I feel as if I may still be missing something.

Comment: I thought your original question was a lot clearer. Showing us input, expected output and actual output was a good idea

Comment: Well I just thought that it would be beneficial to see what exactly it is I'm inputting, in what format, and what the expected result should be. Essentially though, the problem is that I cannot figure out why exactly in.nextLine() produces a blank String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation [Scanner.nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) says this:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line.

So what the method actually does is **give you whats left on that line only**

So, you need to do this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(_file).useDelimiter("\\s+?|-");
ArrayList<Letter> letters = new ArrayList();
String from = in.next();
String to = in.next();
Letter temp = new Letter(from,to);
in.nextLine(); // <-- this is extra

// now we're ready to read the rest of the stuff
String s = in.nextLine();
temp.addLine(s);
```

Comment: Yea, I figured as much, thanks. Problem is though is that in.nextLine() is not reading info in correctly and is producing a blank result.

Comment: what does your while loop look like for this part?

Comment: I don't currently have one as I removed it for the sake of testing if I can get the Recipient, Writer, and one line of text correctly read in and printed out.

Comment: By the looks of your input, your first line of text is just whitespace though!

Comment: I know it looks that way, but that is just how it formatted on this site. The input file has the two names on the first line, separated by a hyphen, and the first line of text on the next line.

Comment: I've reread the stuff... and I'm about to change my answer lol, stand by

Comment: So what you are saying is that it produced a blank String because it read what it thought was the line but was really the remaining whitespace from the first line?

Comment: I implemented that into  my code and it got me further than before. It printed the first word, but I think my whitespace delimiter is stopping it there. I think now I just need play with the delimiters and some conditionals. Thank you so much for the help! I'll update later on whether or not I could manage that.

Comment: UPDATE:
I modified the whitespace delimiter with the greedy quantifier "\\s{2,}" and the entire line printed!

Comment: FINAL UPDATE: I have finished the entire code segment! I have while-loops and if conditionals such that the names are read in correctly and no matter how many lines of text are in between the names and the delimiter "***", they are correctly placed into the body of the letter! Again, thank you so much! I am really new to reading in input data from a file and it is a little nerve-racking.